# How to create a daynamic View with Button and text field from two external XML source

Tags: android, button, android-layout, dynamic, onclick

I was wondering  if it's possible to create a dynamic View from an external XML 
source (server).
The external XML must include information about the layout that contain the button and text field .
The program must to be "dummy", all the logic and  the location of the button and text field must come from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project like this,its possible but you need to process programmatically the data coming in from the xml.I am using json instead of xml